# Featured image, theme

Tags: discussion, featured-photo

I would find it more interesting/organized if there was a theme to follow for the featured images each week. For example, this week post only pictures of cars, flowers, landscape or whatever and change the theme every week.

Answer (score 5):

Hmmmm... It seems like that could be something to consider doing when our group is larger, but right now it's not as though we're getting so many entries that it is overwhelming. My concern in adding a theme is that we'd cut the number of entries in half if a theme were introduced.

There's also the notion of who comes up with the themes? Would the mods be in charge of coming up with something, or would someone need to maintain a weekly thread for voting on the theme like we already do for the picture? Sounds like adding quite a bit more admin work to something that really works fine as it is...

Comment: I was thinking exactly the same problem as your second paragraph. Afterall, then we might have to introduce themes for the theme thread, etc.

Comment: On the other hand, a theme might "level the playing field" a little.  With a wide open contest, the quality of images we are getting (often from the same group of people) are quite amazing, which may make it intimidating for other people (me, for instance) to even enter.  I submitted a few photos in the early days, one of which placed second one week, but which would probably not even be in the running any more.

Answer (score 3):

If we ever did end up using a theme week, I'd like to suggest that we have a "un-edited" week, so the challenge would be to get the best photo out of your camera.  Many of the photos seem to have a lot of post-processing.  I'm not suggesting this is bad - the photos are stunning - but I bet there are a lot of excellent photographers out there who are not necessarily photo-editing gurus (or is that now a required skill to be a good photographer?).

Comment: I think RAW isn't the right idea. If you shoot RAW, yes post is required.

Comment: Sorry, I meant un-edited - ie. the challenge is trying to get the best shot out of your camera.  I will re-word my post.

Comment: I have one of those cameras which do not shoot at 210 px height :( Perhaps resizing and sharpening (unsharp mask) should be allowed?

Comment: <sigh> yes, you would have to resize the photo (but I'd suggest no cropping/straightening), and I guess sharpening would be OK.  I really didn't think this was a stupid idea...

Comment: I think there's reasonable rules for "un-edited" that we could come up with. In fact, we even have a question on that! http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9693/image-processing-editing-what-is-an-unmanipulated-image

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a good idea too. I think @Jay brings up a good point about managing the which weeks have themes and what the themes are. I figure interested parties can hash out a system if we do choose to go with themes.

Here are a few random ideas (one stolen from @seanmc):

- Unedited (strait from the camera, make it as perfect as you can with nothing but physical equipment)
- Photomanipulated (do something unconventional, add photographic elements and blend together a new reality...or surreality, or something completely unreal!)
- Brilliant Sunsets
- Monstrous Mountains
- Micro Macros
- Pure Portraiture
- Dripples (closeup water shots...ripples, drips, droplets, etc.)
- Birds of a Feather (any shot of birds)
- Wild Life (wildlife..duh!)
- City Life
- Nuanced Night (any shot from nighttime)
- Astrophotography

As an added thought, from a management perspective, it might be good to have a "Theme Announcement" thread a week ahead of time to give people time to go out and get a shot for the upcoming theme (if the next week IS a theme...to @dpollitt's point it might be best not to have every single week be a theme week.)

Comment: If we are worried about it being too much work, we could make it a quarterly thing, and publish a schedule so the theme is known weeks or months ahead of time.

Comment: I personally am not really worried. It would be another thread to manage, and possibly a chat every couple weeks to determine what the next theme might be. However, I won't be a mod forever, and I am not sure who might take up the role after my term is up. It would be good to hear from others whether they think it might be too much of a management hassle. (I think PhotoSE is a breeze to moderate...this place runs like a well-oiled machine!)

Answer (score 1):

Yes! This is a good idea. It would add some interest and focus to the pictures of the week contest.

Answer (score 0):

The contest idea, this is similar to many photo sites I am familiar with in the past.

Personally I don't typically have time to go out and shoot the theme every week, so I would likely participate less if ever.

It does have some merit to expand your portfolio or challenge one, but it's just not my favorite way to shoot or think about shooting.

Comment: Every week wouldn't necessarily need to be a theme week. You also wouldn't necessarily be required to shoot something new...if you have an old existing photo that fit the theme, there is no reason you couldn't post that. ;)

Comment: Most contests I have read the rules for require new images, so I just figured.

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest a sports theme soon? I have not seen one yet, and have searched in the suggestiions.

I am fairly new to this site so do excuse if there has been a few already as I have searched but I do not want to manualy go through the archives of every week.